# Why does my flutter app crash when I add `sqflite` to my pubspec.yaml?

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, sqflite

When I add sqflite as a dependency to my project my application crashes. Just adding the dependency crashes the application.

I've tried adding permissions like 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` but that didn't fix the problem.

My pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http:
  video_player:
  screen:
  sqflite:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons:

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/logo.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
```

How to prevent this crash?

Comment: Would you mind including the crash log in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what is problem without crash log,

You can check [this](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/233) link.

If that is not problem

1. Try to run flutter clean.
2. Change version of `sqflite` plugin version.
3. If you are using android emulator, wipe emulator data and try again.
4. Checkout [those](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues) plugin issues (open and closed both).